# Laravel guzzleHttp error 302 and return null value

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm creating a Laravel project that getting data from API using guzzleHttp request. But getting error 302. I've tried using options 'allow_redirects'=>false but still not working. here piece of my code, hope you guys understand what my problem is and sorry for my bad english.

```
$list_receiveItem = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$data['access_token'],
        'X-Session-ID' => $xsessionID,
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ])->withOptions([
        'allow_redirects' => false  
    ])->get($host.'/api/item/list.do',[
        'query_param' => [
            'fields' => 'id,name,no',
            'filter.itemType' => 'INVENTORY'
        ]
    ]);
```

here's the result when I dd the $list_receiveItem :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrPXt.png)

edited :
here's the error I got from postman :
[Error From Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrPXt.png)

Comment: try again with: 'allow_redirects'=> true

Comment: thanks for your reply. i've tried it too but it return error Will not follow more than 5 redirects. I don't redirect anything though.

Comment: have you tried using postman?

Comment: i haven't try it because i don't really understand how to use postman. lol. I'll try use postman then.

Comment: hello @Lee I've edited my post with image I got from Postman. maybe you can help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunely, I send a wrong URL in http get, so that's why I'm getting this error.

I've solved this issue.

Thank you so much.